# Selectively add SQL to view query after search filter is populated in Drupal 7

Tags: php, sql, drupal, drupal-7

I'm trying to search using an SQL query, I need to search two different things "title" and "title_alt" using user input, I think I can do this using OR however I need to be able to adjust the query when a filter is populated. it's my first day using Drupal and I'm still getting to grips with SQL.

I know I can use `explode` and `str replace` but should I add a hook and how do I go about testing for a value in my filter?

Answer (score 0):

you should create a custom module, then implement hook_views_query_alter().

this is a very fast snippet, adjust to your needs

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_query_alter().
 */
function mymodule_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  if ($view->name == 'view_machine_name') {
    if (isset($view->args[0]) && is_numeric(($view->args[0]))) {
      $query->add_where(0, 'users.uid', 1, '>');
      $query->where[0]['type'] = 'OR';
    }
  }
}
```